# CaptureFromFile failing (PyOpencv)

Tags: python, opencv

I had a sample code running on my machine which doesn't run on another.
In particular, that code just does :

```
from cv2 import cv
try: capture = cv.CaptureFromFile('clip.avi')    
except: print 'error loading the video' 
nFrames = int( cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print nFrames
```

On the machine which fails, the result is that nFrames = 0 (as well as the width, height, fps, fourcc etc.), but no exception is raised. I tried using an uncompressed video to make sure there is no codec issues. It also doesn't work with an MPEG1 video, nor any other videos I tried.
So :

- Is-there a way to know what's going on, since there is no error
  handling here (no exception raised, no error message, and I didn't
  find a "GetLastError" function in pyOpenCV) ?
- Any idea what could be the issue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path in the call to `CaptureFromFile()`:

```
capture = cv.CaptureFromFile('/Users/user_name/Videos/clip.avi')
```

Comment: whaoo, this was a quite old question! ;) I can't try it out anymore, but I think we finally solved the problem by reinstalling pyOpencv and maybe codecs as well (someone else finally took care of fixing it). Thanks anyway! :)